# How can the options for an enumerable attribute be displayed in a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums, erb

If I have a model where one attribute can be set only to several predefined values, like this:

```
class Painting < ActiveRecord::Base
  SALE_STATUS = ["for sale", "sold"]
  validates_inclusion_of :status, :in => SALE_STATUS
end
```

Is there a way to write an ERb/HTML form so that the input field for `status` would only display something like a radio button or checkbox for each of the available options?

```
<%= form_for @painting do |painting| %>
  <%= painting.check_box :status # ... don't know how to implement!
<% end %>
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could do something like this:

```
<%= form_for @painting do |painting| %>
  <% Painting::SALE_STATUS.each do |sale_status| %>
    <%= painting.check_box :status, sale_status %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But this code allow the user to choose none of the Sale Status. If you want to allow null values for the status, add this to your model:

```
validates_inclusion_of :status, :in => SALE_STATUS, :allow_nil => true
```

If not, use radio buttons instead:

```
<%= form_for @painting do |painting| %>
  <% Painting::SALE_STATUS.each do |sale_status| %>
    <%= painting.radio_button :status, sale_status %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I gave it a try! But setting `:value =>` to `sale_status` doesn't seem to change the value that the checked box submits; all boxes return a value of "1" instead of "For sale" or "Sold": `<input id="painting_sale_status" name="painting[sale_status]" type="checkbox" value="1" />`

Comment: Try this: `<%= painting.radio_button :status, sale_status %>` (same with check_box)

Comment: That works, thanks for your help. Just making sure I understand this - the second argument for radio_button or check_box determines which value is submitted? The [API entry for these](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-radio_button) is sort of confusing to me.

Comment: Yes, the documentation is confusing because it is talking about the helper method `check_box`, not the `f.check_box` (where `f` comes from the `form_for`). You don't need the first argument 'object_name' because you're using the form_for with an object `@painting`